How do I customize the draw_item method in UI List
I created a ui list in which each item in the list has 3 properties--name, type, and number.  In the list in my panel, I would like to have the type and number, but not the name.  Here is my Python code:
import bpy
from bpy.types import  PropertyGroup, UIList, Operator, Panel
from bpy.props import StringProperty, FloatProperty, CollectionProperty, IntProperty

class CustomItem(PropertyGroup):
    """Group of properties representing an item in the list."""

    name: StringProperty(name="Name")

    type: StringProperty(name="Type")

    number: FloatProperty(name="min",)

class LIST_OT_NewItem(Operator):
    """Add a new item to the list."""
    bl_idname = "my_list.new_item"
    bl_label = "Add an item"

    def execute(self, context):
        item_list=context.scene.my_list
        item_value=context.scene.my_list_item
        item=item_list.add()
        item.name = "Name"
        item.type = "Height"
        item.number = context.scene.my_list_item
        return{'FINISHED'}

class UI_TEST_LIST(UIList):
    """Demo UIList."""

    def draw_item(self, context, layout, data, item, icon, active_data, active_propname, index):

        custom_icon = None
        split = layout.split(factor=0.3)
        split.label(text = item.type)
        split.label(text = str(item.number))

        # Make sure your code supports all 3 layout types
        if self.layout_type in {'DEFAULT', 'COMPACT'}:
            layout.label(text=item.name)

        elif self.layout_type in {'GRID'}:
            pass
        return
  
class VIEW3D_PT_ListTestPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Test List Panel"""
    bl_label = "List"
    bl_idname = "VIEW3D_PT_ListTestPanel"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "List"
    
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        row = layout.row()
        row.template_list("UI_TEST_LIST", "Test List", context.scene, "my_list", context.scene, "my_list_index",rows = 5)
        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(context.scene,"my_list_item")
        row.operator("my_list.new_item",text="Add")


classes = (VIEW3D_PT_ListTestPanel, UI_TEST_LIST, LIST_OT_NewItem, CustomItem)

def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
    bpy.types.Scene.my_list = CollectionProperty(type=CustomItem)
    bpy.types.Scene.my_list_index = IntProperty(name="my_list_index")
    bpy.types.Scene.my_list_item = FloatProperty(name="my_list_item")
        
def unregister():
    for cls in reversed(classes):
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)

Even if I just set name to "", the UI List still leaves space for it.  I would like the other two properties to fill up the space, horizontally.

This should be a minimal working example.
def draw_item(self, context, layout, data, item, icon, active_data, active_propname, index):
    row = layout.row(align=True)
    row.prop(item, "type")
    row.prop(item, "number")

IMO you can start worrying  about the different layout types (compact, grid, default) when you've figured out how UI lists work. In most cases you don't really need them.

Don't draw the name label or do not use use split factor. The value 0.3 would reserve too much space for the number even if you won't draw name.

Actually, I don't think the split factor is relevant.  The problem is that I don't understand the layout types and I did not realize that I was using DEFAULT layout (and the layout.label(text=item.name) line).
